# XlEventRegister to catch event xlCalculationEnded

Tags: xll

I am trying to implement the xlCalculationEnded event using xll sdk. Used XlEventRegister to register the same in my xll addin which is compiled as .xll file. Checked Steve Dalton's book on xll sdk and msdn , don't see any example or documentation on how to implement this event.

Tried googling , no luck.

Please provide an example if there is one.

Note: I have implemented udf which gives me selected range of data, but if there are Excel builtin or any other add-in related functions in the same range, I am not getting calculated values, rather it call udf before excel completes the calculation. That is the reason why I am trying to register the above call back which can give me info on Excel calculation.

Comment: I found this post , it may help you even those it does not fit exactly your question . At least the logic is provided : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/faa95526-523c-4ac1-a8c8-bb52cde63263/an-xll-that-crashes-excel-when-dragging-a-sheet-to-another-workbook?forum=exceldev

Comment: Thank you Malick, I referred this link before to implement, but callback is not getting fired when Excel completes calculation.

Comment: I never tried it, I will have a look to it this weekend if no one come up with a answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just tested [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/faa95526-523c-4ac1-a8c8-bb52cde63263/an-xll-that-crashes-excel-when-dragging-a-sheet-to-another-workbook?forum=exceldev) code and it works , the event is fired at every calculation. I have just added an Event function and modifiy a bit :

1- Modify in xlAutoOpen(void)

```
Excel12f(xlEventRegister, 0, 2, (LPXLOPER12)TempStr12(rgFuncs[i][0]), TempInt12(xleventCalculationEnded));
```

to

```
Excel12f(xlEventRegister, 0, 2, (LPXLOPER12)TempStr12(L"EventOnCalc"), TempInt12(xleventCalculationEnded));
```

2- create the event function :

```
__declspec(dllexport) void WINAPI EventOnCalc()
{
    Excel12f(xlcAlert, 0, 1, TempStr12(L"On Calc event !"));
}
```

I tested and the EventOnCalc() event is fired.

Comment: Thanks Malick, I did not get a chance to post my answer last week. It is working now.